# <a> tag does not obey same width/height as <img> making image overflow

Tags: html, css

I have the following html

```html
 <div class="image-wrap">
    <img src="{{p.image_url}}">
 </div>
```

and CSS

```css
.image-wrap{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 90%;
height: 70%;
margin:0 auto;
}


.image-wrap img{
    max-width: 75%;
    max-height: 75%;
}
```

and that works like a charm ( see below ).

[image]

Now, I want the image to be a hyper-link to the displayed image, thus im wrapping it in an `<a>` tag

```html
 <div class="image-wrap">

   <a href="{{p.image_url}}"><img src="{{p.image_url}}"></a>

 </div>
```

an removes the heigh/width properties from `<img>` to `<a>` like

```css
.image-wrap{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 90%;
height: 70%;
margin:0 auto;
}

.image-wrap a{
    max-width: 75%;
    max-height: 75%;
}

.image-wrap a img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

As you can see, the images now overfloats even though `<a>` has the exact same size properties that `<img>` had, and that worked.

How come?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.image-wrap a{
max-width: 75%;
max-height: 75%;
display: block;
object-fit: cover;
```

}

Comment: That didnt have any effect

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image-wrap a{
    max-width: 75%;
    max-height: 75%;
}

.image-wrap a img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

if your trying to effect also the size of the link and the size of the img the syntax is wrong it should be

```css
.image-wrap, a{
    max-width: 75%;
    max-height: 75%;
}

.image-wrap, a, img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

as you can see i added a comma between each selector that i wanted to group

Comment: I want to change the width/height of the `img` within the `a` tag

Comment: could you share your HTML code  also with css

Answer (score 0):

For the height to work, it has to  be a block element. Try setting "display:block;" to the a element.

Comment: that did not have any effect

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the `img` tag outside the `anchor` tag and absolute positioning the latter.

```css
.image-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.image-wrap img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.image-wrap a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="{{p.image_url}}"></a>
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e">
</div>
```

Comment: It sort of does the right thing, but the image is now in the very upper left corner

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try inline css for img tag:

```
<a href="{{p.image_url}}">
```

Comment: Try using this:<div class="image-wrap">
<a href="{{p.image_url}}">
<img src="{{p.image_url}}" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
</a>

 </div>